# show data from 2 tables laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, show

I have a problem showing data from 2 tables with an id, in laravel 6. My tables are "users" and "companies".

**users**

```
id
name
last name
```

**companies**

```
id
company
address
id_user
```

**Model user**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Company','id_user','id');
}
```

**Model company**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
       $companies = Company::with('user')->find($id);
       return view('clients.show', compact('companies'));

}
```

**view**

$companies->company

but the problem is that is not showing data from users table, can someone help me?

Comment: I have a few questions here. First, in the view you have a variable $companies though your query is going to return a single company and you are accessing the company attribute which I assume is a string like a company name? Second, I assume a company can have many users so you may want to name that relationship users and so that relationship should return a hasMany. Therefore the inverse relationship company on the user model should return a belongsTo.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key name for user in companies table should be 'user_id' not 'id_user'
If you want to use custom column name make sure you pass it to the second argument of the relationship.
Model company:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_user');
}
```